# calling function several times

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have another problem with my text game. I have written a function that generates a random mob depending on the roll.

```
 def random_mob():
        roll = twenty_sided_die.roll()
        if roll <= 5 :
            return Zombie()
        elif roll <= 10:
            return Ghul()
        elif roll <= 15:
            return Skeleton()
        elif roll <= 19:
            return Ghost()
        else:
            return Slime()
    mob = random_mob()
```

Than I have a function called encounter:

```
def encounter():
    for command, action in hero.COMMANDS.items():
        print("Press {} to {}".format(command, action[0]))
    while True:
        command = input("~~~~~~~Press key to continue~~~~~~~")
        if command not in hero.COMMANDS:
            print("Not a valid command")
            continue
        print("You are fighting " + mob.name)
        print("")
        time.sleep(1)
        break
    while True:
        if command:
            hero.COMMANDS[command][1]()
            PlayerAttack()
            time.sleep(1)
            if mob.hp > 0:
                MonsterAttack()
                time.sleep(1)
                if hero.hp <= 0:
                    print("++++++You were killed++++++")
                    break
                    time.sleep(1)
                else:
                    continue
```

When calling the function, random monster is being generated,fight and rolls begins. After each successful roll, monster looses its HP.

After the function ends I would like to call next encounter in the way that again a random mob is being generated and the fight starts over

Problem I have, that if I call encounter() again, it generates the same monster, with HP from previos fight, and the function ends after one roll.

How to deal with it?

Comment: `mob` is the same variable all along your code, it is normal that you always have the same monster. Another approach would be to give the result of your dice to your function or to make a factory to create monsters (See http://python-3-patterns-idioms-test.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Factory.html)

Comment: "if I call encounter() again, it generates the same monster," => actually, `encounter` doesn't "generates" any monster, it uses the global variable `mob`.

Comment: is there a way to 'reset' this variable so every time the result is different ?
@Algorys could You please explain a little bit how to apply factory here?
I'm new to programming and have just started python, and any advices are much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You are not initializing hit points for the monster. Maybe mob should be an array, where you append/push new monster by encounter() method/function. Then, if during the fight the monster is killed you remove/pop it. For example (the monster to fight next is on top of the stack in this example, if the stack is empty fight is over):

```
#begin game    
mob = []
```

...

```
# add monster object to the stack
mob.push(random_mob())
```

...

```
if mob.hp > 0:
   #do fighting
else:
   # remove monster object from the stack
   mob.pop()
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I think you've to **learn how Python works** and how variables manage their `scope` inside packages, classes and functions.

You should also learn more about general programming with objects to get started on a good foundation. You can find lots of tutorials on the web.

As said in the comments, your main problem is that your variable `mob` is never modified!

Here's an example of a factory that can randomly generate monsters when you call the function `encounter()`:

```py
from random import randint


class Zombie(object):
    pass


class Ghul(object):
    pass


class Skeleton(object):
    pass


class Ghost(object):
    pass


class Slime(object):
    pass


class MobFactory(object):
    # create() function will return a mob depending of roll value
    @staticmethod
    def create(roll):
        if roll <= 5:
            return Zombie()
        elif roll <= 10:
            return Ghul()
        elif roll <= 15:
            return Skeleton()
        elif roll <= 19:
            return Ghost()
        else:
            return Slime()


def encounter():
    roll = randint(1, 20)
    mob = MobFactory.create(roll)
    print(mob.__class__)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Here I simulate multiple call of encounter()
    for _ in range(0, 3):
        encounter()
```

I hope it will help you.